# Problems sending requests to an API

Tags: python, rest, api, python-requests, postman

I've got a problem....
I want to get a correct response from an API of a game I'm playing but it doesn't work properly.
I have tested it with python's *requests* library, as well as with Postman. With python it just won't work and I don't understand why. With Postman it worked at the very first time...

Here is my python code:

```
body = {
    "ids":[
        "831e8094-581c-4ccc-a6a2-62c887dee9a1" # this is my account id or so, but it doesnt matter if u have it, just test it
    ],
    "appBundle":"com.deemedyainc.duels",
    "appVersion":"0.6.6",
    "platform":"Android"
}

headers = {
    "Expect": "100-continue",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Unity-Version": "2018.2.14f1",
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "User-Agent": "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-G955N Build/NRD90M)",
    "Host": "api-duels-test.galapagosgames.com",
    "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
}
url = "http://api-duels-test.galapagosgames.com/general/login"
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
```

and the response im getting is *400 Bad Request*

My Postman request:

Body:
[image: Body]

Header:
[image: Headers]

The URI is guaranteed the same.
Maybe it has to do with that they're using the websockets protocol instead of the plain HTML protocol? But why would it work with Postman then? I don't think Postman uses the websocket protocol too

Please guys, I need your help... :D
thanks :)

Comment: as a sanity check, is url the same? in Postman and in code? I tested your code and got a `400 Bad Request`

Comment: In postman, you can save to python. - try it, its something in your headers.

Comment: If you have postman, try it with that, it will work... And yes the Uri is definitely the same

Comment: @JulianCamilleri rly? I will have a look, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it lets you save to code (curl, python (requests or xhr) etc ....) - give it a try :)

Comment: Postman will provide cookies from your browser, where requests won’t because it doesn’t run in the browser. GETting the login page often sets a cookie. You should a) use an app like Telerik Fiddler to spy on your browser get of the login page and the log in, and b) use a requests session to get the login page and do the login, adding any needed headers.

Comment: It seems the `Transfer-Encoding` header is causing the 400 response; I was able to get a 200 response without it. In fact, it seems you don't need any of those headers.

Comment: @t.m.adam thanks brother, that was the solution. Thank you very much <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit late, but I wanted to add the solution because t.m.adam just wrote it as a comment:
As t.m.adam wrote:
the solution was to remove the "Transfer-Encoding" header key.